# "Device Not Ready" when attempting to connecting an old (DOS) hard drive to windows 7

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have an old Western Digital Caviar 2540 hard drive that I am attempting to connect to a Windows 7 machine by using a Bytecc BT-300 USB 2.0 to IDE/SATA Adapter.  I'm connecting things in the right order (power, then sata, then usb) and the jumper settings on the drive are at present set to slave, but am still having an issue.

I am recieving a message that the drive is not initialized.  When I go into Computer Management I can see the drive (as "Disk 5, Unknown, Not Initialized"), but when I attempt to initialize it or right-click and select "Offline" It tells me that "the device is not ready".  Is there something that I can to to get around this, connect the drive and copy the data that I need off of this drive?  Is there a third party tool available that I can use?

Comment: First question:  Are you sure the disk is actually spinning?

Comment: 2nd question: How did you hook up SATA to that 40-pin EIDE drive? :)

Comment: Is the IDE connection good physically? do you have other hard drives to compare the physical connection with? you might find some hard drives it fits more deeply than others. if it goes in more deeply in others then it's not going deeply enough with this one. This USB-IDE adaptor -purple one - that design, goes in nicely to any of my hard drives http://www.pchost.hu/aruhaz/images/usb%20ide%20adapter.jpg   but another I have doesn't i.e. don't go in deeply enough.

Comment: Connect the adapter to the drive BEFORE applying power!  That is, make all connections to the HDD, then power up the drive, then finally make USB connection to PC.  The IDE interface is not hot plug-able.  Also void moving/touching the drive while it's powered.

Comment: @sawdust i'd add to that, while moving isn't really the issue with this one, it's good practice as you suggest, and a good way to power it up is via the mains switch 'cos then nothing moves other than the switch.

Comment: That is an old RLL hard drive, ATA 2 communications standard, a usb adapter will not work unless you have a really old one. You will need an old system (motherboard) that understands rll hard drives to be able to communicate with the drive....http://www.wdc.com/en/products/legacy/Legacy.asp?Model=AC2540

Answer (score 1):

Once you've confirmed the drive is running, then if it's the only drive on that USB adapter/controller then the drive should be set to "Single" mode (no jumper at all, or in the "neutral" position).

[image: WD Jumper Block]